# Why do I get an ANR when I close my android App with a service and a TMultiView in drawer-mode

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

my Delphi android app has a sticky service running all the time, and I uses a TMultiView in drawer mode. When I close both the service and the app, I now almost everytime get an ANR after 2-4 minutes, and while waiting on the ANR (the app isn't visible) I can't start the app, it only shows the splash screen.
But if I changes the mode for the TMultiView to Panel, I have no problems when closing the app.
I think it startet when I was upgrading to Delphi 11, but I am not sure.

I tried to make a simple test, but it unfortunately only gets an ANR every 5-10 times I close the app, but here is the code for the test:

```
interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.MultiView,

  System.Android.Service, Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText, Androidapi.Helpers;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    mltvw1: TMultiView;
    btn1: TButton;
    procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FService: TLocalServiceConnection;

    procedure ServiceConnected(const ALocalService: TAndroidBaseService);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
//var
//  LIntent: JIntent;
begin
  FService := TLocalServiceConnection.Create;
  FService.OnConnected := ServiceConnected;

//  LIntent := TJIntent.Create;
//  LIntent.setClassName(TAndroidHelper.Context.getPackageName(), TAndroidHelper.StringToJString('com.embarcadero.services.ServiceTest'));
//  TAndroidHelper.Activity.startService(LIntent);

  FService.BindService('ServiceTest');
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FService.LocalService.JavaService.stopSelf
end;

procedure TForm1.ServiceConnected(const ALocalService: TAndroidBaseService);
begin

end;
end.
```

And the service

```
interface

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  System.Android.Service,
  AndroidApi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  Androidapi.JNI.Os,
  Androidapi.JNI.App;

type
  TDM = class(TAndroidService)
    function AndroidServiceStartCommand(const Sender: TObject;
      const Intent: JIntent; Flags, StartId: Integer): Integer;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  DM: TDM;

implementation

{%CLASSGROUP 'FMX.Controls.TControl'}

{$R *.dfm}

function TDM.AndroidServiceStartCommand(const Sender: TObject;
  const Intent: JIntent; Flags, StartId: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := TJService.JavaClass.START_STICKY;
end;

end.
```

Comment: It looks like the mode-property in TMultiView only affects my test tablet (Lenovo TB-8504X with Android 8.1). With my phone (Samsung Galaxy S10e with Android 11) mode doesn't change anything, it always gets an ANR in my production app

Comment: Are you sure your issue is related to the TMultiView and the service combined? It is possible, but it is very unlikely that TMultiView has influence on the service and vice versa. Also you are not using service correctly - you are calling both startService and bindService - and you should be using only one - https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Thank you for helping me. I removed the startService, but unfortunately it didnt change my problem.
I dont know if TMultiView is related, but as I said when I set the mode to Panel, it all works as expected.

Comment: Have you at least figured out whether combination of TMultiView and service creates a problem or you have same issue if you remove TMultiView.

Comment: When I remove the TMultiView I dont have the issue. But again, if TMultiView is not animating (mode=Panel) I also dont have the issue.

Comment: What happens if you remove the service? I suspect that tis is not related to service at all. It is important to correctly pinpoint the problem and provide [mcve] You should also inspect logcat to get more information about the problem See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat

Comment: If I remove the service, it works fine. With the service LogCat says "Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord" and then after some minutes "ANR in com.embarcadero.MultiViewTest" "Reason: executing service com.embarcadero.MultiViewTest/com.embarcadero.services.ServiceTest"

Comment: I think you can safely ignore "Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord". It seems like problem is in restarting the service, but I have just found another possible issue in your service code. You have removed startService, but you have left FService.LocalService.JavaService.stopSelf that should be called for services that are started with startService. Maybe that causes the issues.

Comment: If you still have issue after removing stopService, I would suggest filing report to [Quality Portal](https://quality.embarcadero.com/) It is possible there are some bugs in FMX code and some shutdown logic beyond your own code.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I found an even slower tablet, and then I dont need the MultiView anymore, it fails every time, even after I removed the stopSelf. Now i wil try Quality Portal

Comment: By the way, I reported a bug to embarcadero.
And it was necessary for me to both start and bind the service, because my service has to continue running after the app is closed. 
See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Basics